# How to extract a sentence with start marker?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of strings. I want to extract from each the first sentence starting with `"I am"`. For example:

`"I am OK. How about you?"` -> `"I am OK."`

`"I think I am better than that."` -> `"I am better than that."`

I'm using a very simple function that works most of the time:

```
def extract_sentence(text):
    start_idx = text.find("I am")
    dot_idx = text[pred_idx:].find(".")

    return text[start_idx:start_idx + dot_idx + 1]
```

But it won't work in some instances. For example:

`"I am enjoying https://stackoverflow.com/. People are very helpful there."` -> `"I am enjoing https://stackoverflow."` (should have been `"I am enjoying https://stackoverflow.com/."`)

`"I am worried about Josh"` -> `""` (no ending dot, should have been a copy of the input, i.e. `"I am worried about Josh"`).

I believe some regex would help me here, but I don't know how to start. Any ideas?

Comment: What about `"I am unsure. I am scared. And I am alone."`? Would you only expect the first statement? All of them? The last?

Comment: The first appearance only. I'm editing the question.

Comment: Do you just want everything starting with `I am` to the end of the string or do you always want things until the first `.` you see? What should happen if there's no period to end the sentence like in your `"I am worried about Josh"` example? It seems like you just want everything to the end of the string, so it sounds like you just want `return text[start_idx:]`

Comment: What should the output be for `text = "I am enjoing https://stackoverflow.com/"`? And for `"I am worried about Josh"` do you want a match or not?

Comment: @wkl, Pranav please see my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead to end the match at a period that is followed by whitespace, or the end of the line. Consider the following regex:

```
I am .*?(?:\.(?=\s)|$) 
                      
Explanation:          
I am                   : Literally "I am "
     .*?               : One or more of any character, lazy match
        (?:          ) : Non-capturing group
           \.          : A literal period
             (?=  )    : Positive lookahead
                \s     : Whitespace or end of string
                   |$  : End of string / line
```

[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RtXOGi/3)

If you want to allow multiple characters to end a sentence, modify the regex to match those instead of only a period: `I am .*?(?:[.!?](?=\s)|$)`

In python:

```
import re

strings = """I am OK. How about you?
I think I am better than that.
I am enjoing https://stackoverflow.com/. People are very helpful there.
I am worried about Josh""".split('\n')

regex = re.compile(r"I am .*?(?:\.(?=\s)|$)")

for s in strings:
    print("Input string:\n" + repr(s))
    m = regex.findall(s)
    if m:
        print("Matched string:\n" + repr(m[0]))
    else:
        print("No match")
    print("")
```

which gives the expected output:

```
Input string:
'I am OK. How about you?'
Matched string:
'I am OK.'

Input string:
'I think I am better than that.'
Matched string:
'I am better than that.'

Input string:
'I am enjoing https://stackoverflow.com/. People are very helpful there.'
Matched string:
'I am enjoing https://stackoverflow.com/.'

Input string:
'I am worried about Josh'
Matched string:
'I am worried about Josh'
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to just get everything starting a `I am` and not including any `.` followed by a space (since you want the periods in a URL):

```
import re

text = "I think I am enjoying https://stackoverflow.com/. People are very helpful there."
print(re.search('I am(?:[^\.]|\.(?!\s))*', text).group(0))

text = "I am happy. I am satisfied."
print(re.search('I am(?:[^\.]|\.(?!\s))*', text).group(0))
```

Output:

```
I am enjoing https://stackoverflow.com/
I am happy
```

The regex works because it matches anything starting with `I am`, followed by a repetition of zero or more times (`*`) either a character that's not a period (`[^\.]`) or (`|`) a period that's not followed by whitespace (`\.(?!\s)`). All of that's in parentheses around the `|` with a `?:` at the start to indicate that the group does not need to be matched separately (for efficiency).